# XSLTC redirect:write file= does not respect Ant task destdir attribute

Tags: java, xslt, ant, xalan, xsltc

I have an Ant xslt task that looks like this:

```
<xslt 
     basedir="${target.dir}"
     destdir="${target.dir}"
     style="${target.dir}/event.xsl"
     includes="*.xml"
     excludes="*Common.xml"
     extension=".tmp.log"
     force="yes"
     >
</xslt>
```

Within event.xsl I have a directive:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect"
            xmlns:java="java"
            extension-element-prefixes="redirect"
            >

[other stuff to set $filename]

<redirect:write select="$filename">
```

For Xalan-J this works exactly as expected, where the generated files are written to *destdir*.

I'm trying to remove the Xalan-J dependency to use the default XSLTC in Java 1.4+.  XSLTC does not respect *select* in this context.  Instead, the suggestion was to replace it with:

```
<redirect:write file="{$filename}"
```

This works correctly, except the files are written to the current working directory instead of *destdir*.  The *.tmp.log* files correctly end up in *destdir*.

**Anyone know why *destdir* is getting ignored by XSLTC's *redirect:write*?  And how to fix it?**

There are a few workarounds, like making a build.xml for that directory and use the Ant task "ant" to call with destdir as the working directory.  Or I could fork to effective chdir in Ant to a similar end.  But the kludge would be unnecessary if destdir was respected as it was under Xalan-J.